# Tomcat JDBC driver for postgres 10

Tags: jdbc, postgresql-10

I am running PostgreSQL 10 on my machine and want to deploy a java web application through tomcat that will connect to this PostgreSQL through JDBC. Is there any suggestion about PostgreSQL JDBC driver that will be compatible with PostgreSQL 10; JDK 8, and tomcat 8?
I downloaded 42.2.2 JDBC 42 from [this page](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html) but it did not work, and there are a lot of drivers and I am not able to identify the correct driver

Comment: What "did not work"? What is the code you use to connect? How did you configure Tomcat? What is the error or exception you get?  The version [42.2.2 for JDBC 4.2](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-42.2.2.jar)  is the correct version to download

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'Tomcat JDBC driver for Postgres 10'. There is however a *Postgres* JDBC driver for Postgres 10. JDBC is part of Java and should therefore be compatible with any version of Tomcat.